# How to get data from the form when clicking?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I have form inside the component:

```
const MyPopup = ({ name, authenticity_token }) => {
  <form className="new_review" id="new_review" action="/reviews" acceptCharset="UTF-8" method="post">
    <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓" />
    <input type='hidden' name='authenticity_token' value={authenticity_token} />
    <input value="2" type="hidden" name="review[reviewable_id]" id="review_reviewable_id" />
    <Popup
      // ...
      footer={
        <SendButton
          onClick={() => {
            setMessageShown(true);
          }}
        />
      }
      // ...
    >
    <div className="input-group input-group_indent-b_default">
        <label className="input-group__label" name='review[email]'>email</label>
        <input className="input-group__input" name='review[email]' type="email" />
    </div>
  </form>
```

You need to send the data of this form to the server. Ajax request. How do I get form data when I click on submit?

```
const SendButton = () => (
  <button
    onClick={e => {
      const data = new FormData(e.target);
    }}
    className="button popup-footer__button"
  >
    Отправить
  </button>
);
```

`const data` is empty

Comment: Can you show us what the inputs looks like?

Comment: upd body question

Comment: just provided you codesandbox and working code. Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to abstract the submit functionality away from the button itself. Define a `handleSubmit()` function and pair it with the form's `onSubmit` handler. Let the button be as simple as possible, you can still have it do whatever visual actions or other functionality, but let the form handle the actual submit functionality.

You can do something like the following to extract the data from the form:

Working Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-austin-bhq8m

### MyPopup:

```
import React from "react";
import Popup from "./Popup";

const handleSubmit = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const data = new FormData(e.target);
  const dataIterator = Array.from(data);

  const postObject = dataIterator.reduce((obj, [key, value]) => {
    return {
      ...obj,
      [key]: value
    };
  }, {});

  console.log(postObject);
};

const MyPopup = ({ name, authenticity_token }) => {
  return (
    <form
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      className="new_review"
      id="new_review"
      action="/reviews"
      acceptCharset="UTF-8"
      method="post"
    >
      <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓" />
      <input
        type="hidden"
        name="authenticity_token"
        value={authenticity_token}
      />
      <input
        value="2"
        type="hidden"
        name="review[reviewable_id]"
        id="review_reviewable_id"
      />
      <div className="input-group input-group_indent-b_default">
        <label className="input-group__label" name="review[email]">
          email
        </label>
        <input
          className="input-group__input"
          name="review[email]"
          type="email"
        />
        <Popup />
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

export default MyPopup;
```

### Popup

```
import React from "react";

const Popup = props => {
  return <button type="submit">Submit</button>;
};

export default Popup;
```

The `postObject` includes all the data from the form, I'm assuming this is what you want to do your request :)

Comment: it sends `{"postObject"=>{...}}`, can only send `{...}`?

Comment: @evans hmmm not sure what you mean by that. When you print the postObject, does it have everything you need?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have this:

```
    onClick={e => {
      const data = new FormData(e.target);
    }}
```

As `onSubmit` to your form instead of having it as `onClick` to the submit `button`, the `button` will be responsible for invoking the *form's* `onSubmit` callback function, also give the button `type='submit'`:

```
    onSubmit={e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      const data = new FormData(e.target);
      console.log('works!', data)
    }}
```

**Reproduced:**

```
const MyPopup = ({ name, authenticity_token }) => {
  <form
    className="new_review"
    id="new_review"
    action="/reviews"
    acceptCharset="UTF-8"
    method="post"
    onSubmit={e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      const data = new FormData(e.target);
      console.log('works!', data)
    }}
   >
    <Popup
      // ...
      footer={
        <SendButton
          onClick={() => {
            setMessageShown(true);
          }}
        />
      }
      // ...
    >
  </form>
```

```
const SendButton = () => (
  <button
    type='submit'
    className="button popup-footer__button"
  >
```

Comment: i have in console `works! FormData {}`. FormData is empty again

Comment: @evans what type of components you are using inside of your form?